# System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a has a higher version than referenced assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, startup, .net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.1

I upgraded my ASP.NET CORE application from sdk .NET Core 2.0 to .NET Core 2.1. 
I can run the solution in my localhost but when I deploy it to another server there is an exception. And the exception is below. 
The steps I have done to solve the issue so far are below and it throws the same error with all the modification that I did seems nothing works.
Does anybody have any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Steps I've done:

1. Modify the setting for the project

   ```
    <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
       <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
       <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
       <UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>
       <RazorCompileOnBuild>true</RazorCompileOnBuild>
     </PropertyGroup>
   ```
2. I also added binding redirect in the web.config

   ```
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"
   bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   ```
3. Install .net core 2.1 on the server
4. I also deleted my .vs folder and close my visual studio and open it again.

Exception :

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:error CS1705: Assembly  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: Can cou specify the version of the  System.Runtime package which should be used? Try to change it to 4.2.0.0

Comment: Hi Marvin , Thank you for your response. I couldn't check it on VS Community, I tried to right click to see the version it doesn't show me anything. I saw it's listed under .net core 2.1. I also modify the of System Run time version to 4.2.0.0 in CurrentApplication.deps.json. It still throw the same exception.

Comment: "I can run the solution in my localhost but when I deploy it to another server there is an exception." How did you publish? Self-contained or framework dependent? On the second server, what prerequisites have you installed? Such is critical information which is currently missing.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, i publish it as self contain. I haven't solved this issue. But my other coworker tried to publish from her machine to the server and it work. we have the same credential and code.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. When I added the `Views` folder from the solution to the `publish` folder then the problem went away. For some reason Razor requires these source files to be present in the server **AND up-to-date** even when it compiles them also into .dll. Therefore it is strange indeed that the Views folder is not automatically copied during publish.

I personally made a junction like this

`junction "MyProject\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\linux-x64\publish\Views" "MyProject\Views"`

Alternatively, disabling the following line might help (have not tested but this issue seems to be related since in earlier versions of Net.Core there was no Razor compilation).

`<RazorCompileOnBuild>true</RazorCompileOnBuild>`

to

`<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>`