# ASP.NET API failing to publish on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, swagger

I'm trying to publish an C# API to azure, I followed all the steps in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1) here but for some reason when I publish the application the build succeeds and crashes when this below line gets executed

```
Generating swagger file to 'C:\Users\user\Projs\API\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\swagger.json'.
```

and the only error log that gets printed is

```
Failed to generate swagger file. Error dotnet swagger tofile --serializeasv2 --output "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Projs\API\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\swagger.json" "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Projs\API\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\API.dll" v1

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'




Be sure that the Startup.cs for your application is calling AddSwaggerGen from within ConfigureServices in order to generate swagger file. Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2131205&CLCID=0x409 for more information.
```

This is my startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc(
                    "v1",
                    new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });

        }


  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
            });

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI V1");
            });

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

This is my `.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
      <UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>
      <UserSecretsId>d844b2a8-00b0-473d-8f97-9dca9f2899bd</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45'">
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Model\" />
    <Folder Include="Context\" />
    <Folder Include="Contracts\ServiceResponse\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.1" />
    
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I have tried solutions from these links but none of them worked

[Visual Studio 2017 - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4/42755305)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/160

[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450266/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4-2-1-0-culture-neutra)

Is there a way to fix this?

Update:
I tried a solution that was told by a user in the thread to add binding redirects, I added a `web.config` and a `app.config` and added the bindinds but it still fails to publish

Update 2:
I couldn't find a solution so I installed .net 5.0 and it worked

[image]

Comment: Can you see your swagger endpoint? It seems related to your SwashBuckle.AspnetCore version but cannot confirm it, maybe downgrading version of the nuget could help.

Comment: @Juanma Feliu when I go to ```https://localhost:44342/swagger/v1/swagger.json``` it shows the JSON perfectly

Comment: Your Newtonsoft.Json version can be messed up too since Pomelo uses a lower version than 13.0.1. Can you edit your .csproj and remove the System.Runtime package reference?

Comment: @Juanma Feilu I removed the System.Runtime and deleted Newtonsoft.Json as well because I'm not using it. But I still get the same error

Comment: add a nuget package screenshot from your project please.

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu I added the screenshot!

Comment: Since your project targets netcoreapp3.1, try using all framework nuget packages of version 3.*.* instead of 5.*.*.

Comment: @Prasath everything is on 3.*.* except for swagger because when i downgrade that it doesnt take it as a api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the latest version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.  I found the official workaround here from Swashbuckle on GitHub:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2006

1. Add a global.json file to your Web API project
2. Put this in it:

   {
   "sdk": {
   "version": "3.1.406",
   "rollForward": "latestPatch"
   }
   }

Comment: A note to change the sdk version to the one your project is using.