# RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not to load file or assembly

Tags: .net, frameworks, runtime

IDK why ı got this error?

```
CHCP 65001
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "C:\Users\mesut\Desktop\MySampleSwAddın\MySampleSwAddın\MySampleSwAddın\bin\Debug\net6.0\MySampleSwAddın.dll" /tlb
pause
```

Eror Message

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450266/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4-2-1-0-culture-neutra
ı try these solution but ı got same error